# Bash refuses to escape strings when running `pecl install ibm_db2`

Tags: php, bash, shell, terminal, db2

I'm running `pecl install ibm_db2` and then it asks me to specify my DB2 installation directory (which I'm 98% sure is to my `sqllib` folder). I've given it both `"Library/Application Support/ibm-db2-developerc/DB2/db2fs/config/db2inst1/sqllib"` and `Library/Application\ Support/ibm-db2-developerc/DB2/db2fs/config/db2inst1/sqllib` but both times it stops at the space between `'Application'` and `'Support'` in the path. I've the run `export`command on both of the above paths and also manually set them in my `.bash_profile` but the terminal literally just refuses to acknowledge the space. Any solutions?

Comment: The files the directory you mentioned are from your Db2 Developer-C container; any binaries that you find in that directory are Linux binaries and won't be usable by a PHP install on macOS. You'll need to download the [Db2 client for macOS](https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?parent=ibm%7EInformation%2BManagement&product=ibm/Information+Management/IBM+Data+Server+Client+Packages&release=11.1.*&platform=All&function=fixId&fixids=*-dsdriver*FP003*&includeSupersedes=0&source=fc)

Answer (score 0):

Life is easier if you avoid pathnames and filenames have have whitespace. You can create links to avoid the hassle sometimes.

The pathname should be fully qualified (start with /), not a relative path.
In the example below I assume your path begins /Library, so adjust as necessary for your environment.

Before running the command `pecl install ...` check if any of the following commands lets it work for you. If you still have a problem, specify your operating-system fully (distro,version, bash version etc).

```
export IBM_DB_HOME=/Library/Application\ Support/ibm-db2-developerc/DB2/db2fs/config/db2inst1/sqllib

export IBM_DB_HOME='/Library/Application Support/ibm-db2-developerc/DB2/db2fs/config/db2inst1/sqllib'

export IBM_DB_HOME="/Library/Application Support/ibm-db2-developerc/DB2/db2fs/config/db2inst1/sqllib"
```

When you specify the variable name correctly , pecl should not pause for input of the instance-home directory.